# How to reduce column of JTable in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am using netbeans and trying to use jTable from its designer's section. The default numbers of columns is 4. I want to make it 3 only, but as I click the columnCount it says "Custom Editing of this Property is not Supported".

Can you help me about this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Goto properties of jtable-->select model and create row and column in the tabs given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Right click on table* -> `Table contents...` -> `Columns` tab -> *select column* -> `Delete`

or

*Right click on table* -> `Table contents...` -> `Columns` tab -> *decrement* `Count` (click on the little downwards arrow)

Comment: _Right click on table_ -> `Table contents...` -> `Columns` tab -> _select column_ -> _edit the_ `Title` _text box_